# How to evaluate q-value network of sac agent in stable baselines (on a state-action pair)?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am implementing SAC agent in stable baselines and need to evaluate q-value network inside my custom environment.I have tried to get the q-values from SAC class object, but failed.
Any method or function like the one with PPO (.value) will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We do not evaluate value functions, we evaluate policies.

Comment: No, but I need to evaluate the q-value function inside the environment because I am implementing a special algorithm called Wolpertinger's algorithm